# Magento - New Order mail

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.6.2.

I need to edit the new order mail. Which file is the template for the items?  I need the specific file where the items are being generated and formatted.

Answer (score 3):

I already found it.
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml

Answer (score 2):

To edit the New Order email you go into System -> Transactional Emails and click on 'Add New Template'.

Then you load in the existing New Order template by selecting 'New Order' from the drop down menu in the Template input field and click the 'Load Template' button.  In the Template Information section you assign a new name to your new template and make the modifications to it before hitting 'Save Template'.

To apply it you go to System -> Configuration -> Sales and Select the Sales Emails option.

In the Order tab you apply your newly saved template to the New Order Confirmation Template dropdown.

Do the same for New order from Guest if you are allowing guest checkout.

Comment: I need the specific file where the items are being generated

Answer (score 0):

The email templates are located under /app/locale/en_us/template/email and /app/locale/en_us/template/email/sales.

The disappointing thing about email templates in Magento is that they expect store owners to manage these using the backend rather than by editing the template files. Of course, you can always just edit the templates directly, but make sure to keep backups of them before updating to a new version of Magento.

It ends up being a lot of work, and from what I've seen, mostly clients do little more than update the logo. If your client wants to have fully custom email templates, expect a good 20+ hours to get them right (cross email client compatibility, client changes, etc).

Comment: I need the specific file where the items are being generated