# magento order notification doesn't contain email of a customer

Tags: php, email, magento, notifications, store

I would like to know if there is possibility to include customers email into email notification that is sent to sales person after order is made.

I get all the data like name, last name, address of a customer, ordered items, but no email of a customer. Is there a way to add email of customer to email notifications for sales department?

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to see your customer’s email address in the order confirmation emails sent out by Magento, you will have to edit (or create a new template and assign it to new order emails) the new order confirmation email template and add this code to it.

{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added template and set everything as described, the only problem I have now is that, i cannot find  System->Configuration->Sales in my Magento, so I wonder if this is missing in 1.8.x versions?

Comment: sry for that my friend. I've just found where that is. It's not on drop down menu, but on the left menu bar :D I feel so bad atm :D

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you already have the email template in Transactional emails. If you do not know how to do that you can google it or look  at this Stackoverflow post: [Magento - New Order mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664983/magento-new-order-mail).

In the corresponding transactional email template add the following code wherever you want the email address to appear:

`email: {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}`

regards